# Bash time check script allow 1 minute difference

Tags: linux, bash

I am developing a nagios/collectd check for time checking on each server. I have done bash script to get info from Collectd WSP files and check them against the nagios server time (`date +%s`). Collectd sends the `date +%s` value after 60 seconds has past from the last sending. The problem I am facing is how can I make the check command calculate that if the value is out of sync maximum 60 seconds then everything is OK, if its out of sync over 60 seconds then its critical.

The script:

Time collecting on nagios server and collectd WSP files that other servers send. Each command returns a value in epoch (`$time` is taken from nagios server and `$stime` is taken from collectd WSP files):

```
time=`date +%s`
stime=`whisper-fetch --from=$(expr $(date +%s) - 60) --until=$(date +%s) $WSP_PATH | cut -c1-10`
```

Critical IF statement. If this `$stime` does not match to `$time` got from nagios server then it sends critical. I want this to be, if nagios servers time value is out of sync over 60 seconds compared to WSP output value then its critical else its OK.

```
if [ "$stime" -ne "$time" ] ; then
    echo CRITICAL: Server time is out of sync!
    exit $STATE_CRITICAL
fi
```

OK statement:

```
echo OK: Server time is in sync
exit $STATE_OK
```

Comment: diff=$((sttime-time)); if (( diff < -60 || diff > 60)); then echo "critical"; fi

Comment: I would suggest that you ensure that NTP is in use, and then alert on the observed skew as reported by the likes of ntpstat. 60 seconds is _very_ out of sync for a number of common systems; especially security-related systems such as authentication systems, and logging events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the two times from each other and check if the result is greater than 60. It appears that `bash` doesn't have an operator to compute absolute value, so you have to do the comparison both ways.

```
if [ $[time-stime] -gt 60 ] || [ $[stime-time] -gt 60 ] ; then
```